# Reading data of API in Nodejs and creating object

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

My `API` returns below data in `nodejs`.

`console.log(body)` prints the below.

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "PlanId": 2007,
      "PlanCode": "Future Mat Cost Planning  - Budget",
      "Description": "Future Mat Cost Planning  - Budget",
      "FromMonth": "2019-10-01T00:00:00+00:00"
    },
    {
      "PlanId": 3001,
      "PlanCode": "Nvidia Cost PL",
      "Description": "Nvidia Cost PL",
      "FromMonth": "2019-10-01T00:00:00+00:00"

    },
    {
      "PlanId": 1001,
      "PlanCode": "Material Cost Planning - PO",
      "Description": "Material Cost Planning - PO",
      "FromMonth": "2019-10-01T00:00:00+00:00"
    }
   ],
 "count": 5,
  "hasMore": true,
  "limit": 5,
  "offset": 0
}
```

I have to create object in which I have to store `PlanId` and `plancode`. How can i do that. I need to store data in key value format. can anybody help me to create either array or object? I am new to nodejs
I want result like this.

```
obj=[{
      "PlanId": 3001,
      "PlanCode": "Nvidia Cost PL",
     },
    {
      "PlanId": 1001,
      "PlanCode": "Material Cost Planning - PO",
    }
    ];
```

Comment: What are expected results?

Comment: @charlietfl I have modified the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so you want to `map` the response to a new object?

```
// assuming `body` is the API response

const obj = body
  .items
  .map(item => ({
    PlanId: item.PlanId,
    PlanCode: item.PlanCode,
  });
```